# How to sort out duplicates from a massive list using sort, uniq or awk?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, duplicates

I have a 12Gb file of combined hash lists. I need to find the duplicates in it but I've been having some issues.

Some 920 (uniq'd) lists were merged using `cat *.txt > _uniq_combined.txt` resulting in a huge list of hashes. Once merged, the final list WILL contain duplicates.

I thought I had it figured out with `awk '!seen[$0]++' _uniq_combined.txt > _AWK_duplicates.txt && say finished ya jabroni`

`awk '!seen[$0]++' _uniq_combined.txt > _AWK_duplicates.txt` results in a file with a size of `4574766572` bytes.

I was told that a file that large is not possible and to try again.

`sort _uniq_combined.txt | uniq -c | grep -v '^ *1 ' > _SORTEDC_duplicates.txt` results in a file with a size of `1624577643` bytes. Significantly smaller.

`sort _uniq_combined.txt | uniq -d > _UNIQ_duplicates.txt` results in a file with a size of `1416298458` bytes.

I'm beginning to think I don't know what these commands do since the file sizes should be the same.

Again, the goal is to look through a giant list and save instances of hashes seen more than once. Which (if any) of these results is correct? I thought they all do the same thing.

Comment: well, the last two should be different because the first contains the number of same lines, the other don't.

Comment: @MladenJablanović I'm not sure I'm following. They all sort or manipulate the original file - `_uniq_combined.txt`, no?

Comment: Did you try to get the difference between both `_SORTEDC_duplicates.txt` and `_UNIQ_duplicates.txt` by doing a `diff` or `cmp`? If it tells something, track the line that differs in the original files.

Comment: @oliv I'm not familiar with diff, what would that tell me?

Comment: @dsp_099 It would output the lines that differs between both files...

Comment: BTW the comment of @MladenJablanović is correct. To compare both files you should change the `grep -v  '^ *1 '` by this `sed '/^ *1 /d;s/^ *[2-9][0-9]* //'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` is designed especially to cope with huge files too. You could do:

```
cat *.txt | sort >all_sorted 
uniq all_sorted >unique_sorted
sdiff -sld all_sorted unique_sorted | uniq >all_duplicates
```

Comment: Not sure I understand that last line. Combine all, uniq the combined file, then find the difference between the two and pipe it out?

Comment: also the result of all_duplicates is zero, which is not possible

Comment: The `-s` means that lines common to the left and right argument, are removed. Since the right argument is a subset of the left argument in `sdiff`, it means that the left column contains only the duplicate lines. The `-l` means that we only get the left column printed. Since each duplicate line may occur several times, the final `uniq` is used to compact it. If your final output is empty, you could investigate, where this happens. For example, you could do a `sdiff -d all_sorted unique_sorted|less -n` first and see, where are the duplicates.

Comment: `sort *.txt > all_sorted` would do. And I think you could use `comm -2` for the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` command should work fine with a 12 GB file. And `uniq` will output just duplicated lines if you specify the -d or -D options. That is:

```
sort all_combined > all_sorted
uniq -d all_sorted > duplicates
```

or

```
uniq -D all_sorted > all_duplicates
```

The -d option displays one line for each duplicated element. So if "foo" occurs 12 times, it will display "foo" one time. -D prints *all* duplicates.

`uniq --help` will give you a bit more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you `split` that big file into smaller files, `sort --unique`ed them out and tried to merge them with `sort --merge`:

```
$ cat > test1
1
1
2
2
3
3
$ cat > test2
2
3
3
4
4
$ sort -m -u test1 test2
1
2
3
4
```

I would imagine merging sorted files would not happen in memory?

Comment: the massive file must consist of all the smaller ones because that's how the dupes will make themselves known. list 1, 2, 3, 99, 132 might not have any dupes but list 1 and list 920 might. So hence the merge. My question is why do those commands produce vastly different results?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `awk` script is incorrect and your `uniq -c`-command includes the counts of occurrences of duplicates and `sort _uniq_combined.txt | uniq -d` is the correct thing :) .

Note that you could have directly `sort *.txt > sorted_hashes` or `sort *.txt -o sorted_hashes`.

If you have just two files at hand consider using `comm` (`info coreutils` to the rescue), which can give you columned-output of "lines just in first file", "lines just in second file", "lines in boths files". If you need just some of these columns you can suppress the others with options to `comm`. Or use the generated output as a base and continue working on it using `cut`, like `cut -f 1 my_three_colum_file` to get the first column.