# Sorting and removing duplicates from single or multiple large files

Tags: merge, mergesort

I have a 70gb file with 400 million+ lines (JSON). My end goal is to remove duplicates lines so i have a fully "de-duped" version of the file. I am doing this on a machine with 8cores and 64gb ram.

I am also expanding on this thread, '[how to sort out duplicates from a massive list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221524/how-to-sort-out-duplicates-from-a-massive-list-using-sort-uniq-or-awk)'.

Things i have tried:

- Neek - javascript quickly runs out of memory
- Using Awk (doesn't seem to work for this)
- using Perl (perl -ne 'print unless $dup{$_}++;') - again, runs out of memory

  - `sort -u largefile > targetfile`
    does not seem to work. I think the file is too large.

**Current approach:**

- Split the files into chunks of 5million lines each.
- Sort/Uniq each of the files

`for X in *; do sort -u --parallel=6 $X > sorted/s-$X; done`

Now I have 80 individually sorted files. I am trying to re-merge/de-dupe them them using sort -m. This seems to do nothing as the file/line size ends up being the same.

Since sort -m does not seem to work, i am currently trying this:

```
cat *.json | sort > big-sorted.json
```

then I will try to run uniq with

```
uniq big-sorted.json > unique-sorted.json
```

Based on past experience, I do not believe this will work.

What is the best approach here? How do i re-merge the files and remove any duplicate lines at this point.

**Update 1**
As I suspected, cat * | sort > bigfile did not work. It just copied everything to a single file the way it was previously sorted (in individual files).

**Update 2:** 
I also tried the following code:

```
cat *.json | sort --parallel=6 -m > big-sorted.json
```

The result was the same as the previous update. 
I am fresh out of ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if performance is a big issue, but with a native sorting algorithm like bubble sort, you only need to load two lines at a time compare them, optionally swap them, and write them back.

Comment: And there are probably smarter algorithms that can be used like that, but it may be a bit harder to implement. Anyway, find a solution that allows you to process small chunks of the file rather than trying to load 70gb into memory.

Comment: ok, but what is that solution? So far, the cat * > sort has been running for over an hour with 0 bytes written.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, i found the solution:

```
sort -us -o out.json infile.json
```